# Leaflet.js setView() / fitBounds() does not respect padding

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to zoom in on a marker and put an offset to the left because there is a sidebar. My code looks like this:

```
map.setView(marker._latlng, 14, { paddingTopLeft: [50, 0] });
```

Unfortunately the padding has no effect. Can anyone help?

Comment: Define "has no effect". What happens instead?

Comment: Whether i search with padding or without padding the result is the same.

Comment: Please re-read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-setview and https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#zoom/pan-options - `setView` will ignore the `paddingTopLeft`, and that's expected and documented.